# Создание приложения на Web Sockets

Tags: php, ajax, websocket

1. Собственно, интересует насколько оправдано использование Web Sockets от других технологий динамического взаимодействия, например AJAX?
2. Есть ли более продвинутые технологии чем Web Sockets?
3. Будет ли правильным написать свое приложение на Web Sockets [PHP] (клиент-серверную часть)?
4. Есть ли какие-нибудь грамотные руководства кроме мануала на php.net

Если я что-то не так написал, не обессудьте.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы перефразировал - не на WebSockets, а используя.
Применять ту или иную технологию, стоит исходя из поставленной задачи. Обычные для веба технологии - односторонние, причем инициатором всегда выступает клиент. Сервер попросту не имеет технической возможности выступать в роли инициатора. Некоторая видимость такого поведения имитируется с помощью постоянного опроса сервера. Например, удобно это делать посредством AJAX (не перезагружая страницу). Но в некоторых задачах этого недостаточно. Простой пример - чат. Необходим механизм, который будет достаточно дешево оповещать клиент о наличии нового сообщения. С помощью AJAX добиться этого эффективно - не получится. Чтобы клиент относительно быстро узнавал о новых сообщениях необходимо часто отправлять запросы на сервер. Это создает неоправданную нагрузку. Если схитрить и опрашивать сервер редко - информация будет обновляться с запозданием. Придется искать компромисс. WebSockets - это двусторонний постоянный канал передачи данных, где инициатором может выступать любая из обоих сторон. То есть в этом случае сервер при наличии нового сообщения незамедлительно и одноразово может уведомить только нужного клиента. Таким образом клиент получает возможность незамедлительно реагировать на любые серверные изменения.

1. Учитывая что вопрос о PHP, нельзя однозначно посоветовать использовать или не использовать исключительно WebSockets. Возможно проще окажется спроектировать систему обычным для PHP образом, включая AJAX. А с использованием WebSockets разработать небольшой модуль который будет оповещать клиентов о необходимости обновить данные. Архитектурно это выглядит так - PHP код производит все обычные действия и дополнительно просит WebSockets-модуль уведомить нужного клиента.
2. Смотря что понимать под продвинутостью. К недостатку WebSockets можно отнести что они работают поверх протокола TCP. В некоторых случаях все же удобнее работать с UDP. Но если не стоит задача разработки real-time игры или передачи аудио/видео в реальном времени то WebSockets более чем достаточно.
3. Веб приложение полностью на WebSockets, не самый хороший выбор. Хотя бы с той точки зрения что есть куча статики которую лучше отдавать штатным для сервера образом. Те же представления - статика, и ее лучше отдавать как статику. Посредством WebSockets стоит обмениваться только данными, или что еще проще - только уведомлениями о изменениях на серверной стороне.
4. Для клиентской части советую ознакомиться с [WebSocket](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets)
   Необходимо уяснить только начальную часть - Пример браузерного кода. Все остальное - детали реализации, и абсолютно не обязательно для изучения, но конечно же не помешает. Продублирую:

**Пример браузерного кода**

Для открытия соединения достаточно создать объект WebSocket, указав в нём специальный протокол ws.:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://javascript.ru/ws");
```

У объекта socket есть четыре коллбэка: один при получении данных и три – при изменениях в состоянии соединения:

```
socket.onopen = function() {
  alert("Соединение установлено.");
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
  } else {
    alert('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
  }
  alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
};
```

Для посылки данных используется метод socket.send(data). Пересылать можно любые данные.

Например, строку:

```
socket.send("Привет");
```

Или файл, выбранный в форме:

```
socket.send(form.elements[0].file);
```

Просто, не правда ли? Выбираем, что переслать, и socket.send().

Для того, чтобы коммуникация была успешной, сервер должен поддерживать протокол WebSocket.

Comment: Я вас понял, ну собственно я так и представлял отличия AJAX от Web Sockets. А насчет  руководств? Есть ли какие-нибудь грамотные источники, которые мне позволят научиться писать на Web Sockets

Comment: обновил ответ, так же стоит учесть что серверный код обязан создать слушающий сокет который будет доступен постоянно для входящих соединений. На PHP это можно реализовать в виде консольного скрипта. По хорошему его бы еще допилить до уровня демона, и зарегистрировать в системе, чтобы была возможность штатно его перезапускать, например, при перезагрузке сервера.

Comment: Да демон не нужен это же костыль! Но если только использовать его в качестве перезапуска упавшего сервера, то я полностью согласен! По-поводу источников по Web Sockets для клиентской части: в сети полно источников. Мне нужно для php серверная часть =)