# Частый опрос сторонего сервера через бэкэенд

Tags: php, ajax, клиент-сервер, веб-сервер, протоколы

Пытаюсь реализовать одностраничный сайт, с которым не всё так просто.
Есть такая схема:
(1) клиент,
(2) мой сервер, на котором находится вся логика, php и данные,
(3) сервер стороннего сервиса (к которому доступа я никакого не имею, он служит лишь для вытягивания данных).

Со страницы клиента (1) постоянно требуются запросы на сервер стороннего ресураса (3).
Однако, по причинам безопасности, данные, передаваемые на клиенте (1), не должны отображаться и вообще быть задействованы в запросах к стороннему ресурсу (3).

Поэтому было принято мной решение в выполнении неявных запросов к стороннему серверу (3) через свой (2) при обработке ajax запросов.

То есть получается такое общение серверов и клиента:
(1) => (2) => (3) => (2) => (1)

Опрашивать сервер нужно довольно часто: как только пришел ответ на запрос, можно выждать двухсекундную задержку, а затем ещё посылается такой же запрос. И так бесконечно.

Ну а проблема моя в том, что я чёрт знает сколько сайтов перерыл, но так и не разобрался, как экономично наладить работу на длинные запросы мой сервер и клиентское решение.

Я понятия не имею, как люди учат все эти технологии, но у меня, видит Бог, не получается так, на что постоянно возникают вопросы.
Нашел эту [статью](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-longpoll). Это ли то, что нужно?
Или нужно копать в сторону websocket?
А nodejs поможет тут?

Во всех этих технологиях бекенда я окончательно запутался и прошу помощи в виде простенького примера клиенской части и серверной для этой действительно простой задачи. Или хотя бы ссылки на толковые и вразумительные для полных чайников статьи.

У меня есть маленькая реализация уже, но... Не уверен, так ли нужно это всё делать. И в чём подвох, быстро ли оно будет работать не на локальном, а на виртуальном хостинге.

**Клиент:** (script на клиентском index.html)

```
$.post(
    "/php/test.php",
    {
        u : "Vostok Sisters",
        m : 0,
        type : "string",
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

**Сервер:** (test.php)

```
<?php

$paramsArray = array(
    'k' => '41d3tsd9gh8fdh7f6a68hb89hgjn7sf6',
    'u' => $_POST['u'],
    'm' => $_POST['m'],
    'type' => $_POST['type ']
); 

$vars = http_build_query($paramsArray);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(  
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $vars
    )  
);  
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user_recent', false, $context);
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: @br3t нет. Это не он.

Comment: node.js такая же технология как php

Comment: Это называется не прокси, а обычный RESTful API, т.к. клиент о стороннем сервере не знает.

Comment: @Alex78191 извините, о таком я вообще впервые слышу (: Слабоват я в бекэнде.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585900/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-web-sockets

Answer (score 0):

Если попробовать реализовать пример из статьи, то получится нечто вроде такого:

```js
function subscribe() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/php/test.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      u: "Vostok Sisters",
      m: 0,
      type: "string",
    },
    success: function(respond) {
      console.log(respond);
      // получили ответ - посылаем запрос повторно через 2 сек
      setTimeot(subscribe, 2000);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.error(e);
      // получили ошибку - посылаем запрос повторно через 2 сек
      setTimeot(subscribe, 2000);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Да это-то понятно, я не совсем даун же, чтобы не смочь по аналогии написать.

Comment: Меня интересует, что вообще использовать и почему. Корректный ли такой способ общения с сервером в моей задаче или нет. Вполне нормально ли будет работать в реальных условиях при средней нагрузке в 5к одновременных подключений?

Comment: @VostokSisters подумаешь нагрузка в 2 раза больше только

Comment: @Alex78191 не понял Ваш комментарий... То есть это хорошо? Малое увеличение нагрузки? И пример выше - вполне рабочий вариант в моей задаче? Или нет?

Comment: Работать будет.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets нужно применять когда клиенту нужно получать данные при их обновлении на сервере, тогда сервер может инициировать передачу. А не когда клиент отправляет свои данные.